# mapping each column based on datatype in scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
44,8602,37.19
35,5368,65.89
35,3391,40.64
44,6694,14.98
```

```scala
val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "TotalSpentByCustomer")

val input = sc.textFile("C:\\Spar\cuscopy.csv")

val fields = input.map(x => (x.split("\t")(1).toInt, 1, 2.toFloat, 2))

val d = fields.reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y)

val results = d.collect()

results.foreach(print)
```

Getting error

> value reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int,
> Int, Float, Int)]
> val d = fields.reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y)

Please suggest is it right way to parse fields ?

Answer (score -1):

You could load the csv file to a dataframe with a given schema using the Spark Project SQL library and if needed convert it to a RDD.

```
// remove those lines when not using jupyter
interp.load.ivy("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.2.0")
interp.load.ivy("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.2.0")

import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, FloatType, IntegerType};

val spark = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder
        .master("local")
        .appName("Spark CSV Reader")
        .getOrCreate;

// create a new schema for reading the csv
val schema = new StructType()
      .add("Field1", IntegerType, true)
      .add("Field2", IntegerType ,true)
      .add("Field3", FloatType, true)

val df = spark.read.format("csv")
      .schema(schema)
      .load("/vagrant/test/test.csv") //replace with desired path

// select only column 1 & 2, not sure if this was intended by the questioner 
val selected = df.select("Field1","Field2")

// convert your dataframe to a rdd
val d = selected.rdd

d.collect().foreach(println)
```

This outputs the following lines for the given input from the question

```
[44,8602]
[35,5368]
[35,3391]
[44,6694]
```

Comment: val d = selected.rdd.flatMap(list) ,what is list here ?

Comment: I changed the conversion to the most simplistic one.